# is it possible to automate password generation for GCE in node js

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, cryptography, google-compute-engine

i was wondering if its possible to do this 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/automate-pw-generation#manual_instructions
in node js
im not sure if im doing it right but i am using the crypto module thats built in and have this so far

```
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');

const { publicKey, privateKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {modulusLength: 2048});
```

I think thats the way i should start it ,

All i need is up to step 4, i was stuck at extracting the modulus and the exponent

Comment: Officially GCP supports automatic password generation using [GO, Python, JAVA][1]. There is no official solution to have it done in node.js.

Is there a specific reason why you would like to do it in node.js?  I am asking this because it might take a lot of work compared with the official solutions. [1]: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/automate-pw-generation#automate_password_generation

Comment: @Alioua Im building in application in node js backend and js front end and this is a key feature i want to have

Comment: Unfortunately, currently there is no way to automate password generation using node.js. Perhaps you can file a feature request using [Google’s public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Here is the documentation for filing a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: Google provides examples in three languages. Use that as your example and port to node.